# Need help retrieving value from XML

Tags: xml, t-sql

This is my very first time posting here. so I apologize in advance if I am not asking this in the proper way.

I have been trying to build a query that will return a certain value within my XML based on a specific criteria.

[Screenshot of table where my XML is (xml_bot column)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UMqb.png)

[Screenshot of XML structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VX14B.png)

I don't have experience with handling XML in SQL, and wasn't able to get this to work using the methods I found in other posts. The latest one I tried was the below, but as you can see, I was just trying to get something to return, to at least guarantee that the query was finding something

```
--filtering XML data using XQuery
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES 
('http://www.harlandfs.com/namespaces/hfs/openpath/wrapper/2.0#' AS ns)
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM bde_xml
WHERE xml_bot.exist('(/ns:HFS_MISMORequest/ns:MESSAGE/ns:MESSAGE_DELIVERY_INFORMATION/ns:OriginalMessageIdentifier[.="1090020"])')=1
and application_id = 1522
GO
```

All I want to do is return the content of the OriginalMessageIdentifier Node (in this case, 123456) based on the app add:

```
select [value within OriginalMessageIdentifier node]
from bde_xml
where application_id = 1522
```

The result would be: 123456

11111111
          123456
          https://thisisatest.com

My biggest struggle is with the several nodes prior to OriginalMessageIdentifier, and how they have ns declared.

Would someone be able to point me in the right direction?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

First, for this kind of thing you'll get help faster by including actual code instead of a screenshot. When dealing with namespaces you can cheat (usually) by using "any namespace" syntax or you can be explicit as detailed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/add-namespaces-to-queries-with-with-xmlnamespaces?view=sql-server-2017).

Here's how we get what you're looking for when dealing with a single XML object:

```
DECLARE @XML XML =
'<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://whatever">
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://yyy.xyz.com">
    <HFS_BLAH_BLAH xmlns="http://123.456.999">
      <OriginalMessageID>12345</OriginalMessageID>
    </HFS_BLAH_BLAH>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>';

SELECT @XML.value('(//*:OriginalMessageID/text())[1]', 'int');
```

Against a table, because you're returning a single atomic value you can do this:

```
-- Sample data
DECLARE @yourtable TABLE (someId INT Identity, SomeXML XML);
INSERT @yourtable (SomeXML)
VALUES
('<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://whatever">
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://yyy.xyz.com">
    <HFS_BLAH_BLAH xmlns="http://123.456.999">
      <OriginalMessageID>12345</OriginalMessageID>
    </HFS_BLAH_BLAH>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>'),
('<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://whatever">
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://zzz.xyz.com">
    <HFS_BLAH_BLAH xmlns="http://123.456.999">
      <OriginalMessageID>999666333</OriginalMessageID>
    </HFS_BLAH_BLAH>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>');

-- Solution
SELECT t.someId, OId = t.SomeXML.value('(//*:OriginalMessageID/text())[1]', 'int')
FROM @yourtable AS t;
```

**Which returns:**

```
someId      OId
----------- -----------
1           12345
2           999666333
```

Comment: Thank you Alan! Sorry I never reached back out. This was extremely helpful and I was able to apply it to my project. Next time, I will be more specific/clear and include my code. Thanks again!!